# How to pass file dialog Instance as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to compare two images by using picture box, but I got a problem: How can I pass the selected picture name as a parameter to a function as a string?

I save picture path and name as a `string name1` and `string name2`, but I got a problem when I pass them as parameters.

Below is my code. Please tell me where I am wrong.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd1.Title = "Select User Profile Image";
    ofd1.Filter = "Image File(*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
    if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd1.FileName);
        string name1 = ofd1.FileName;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Compare(name1,name2);
}

public void Compare(string bmp1, string bmp2, byte threshold = 3)
{
    Bitmap firstBmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(bmp1);
    Bitmap secondBmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(bmp2);
    firstBmp.GetDifferenceImage(secondBmp, true);
    string result = string.Format("Difference: {0:0.0} %", firstBmp.PercentageDifference(secondBmp, threshold) * 100);
}
```

Comment: "but i got a problem when i pass as a parameter "   What exactly is the nature of your problem?

Comment: name1 and name2( there is no name2 field in your code) are not accessable in button1_Click() make them global

Answer (score 4):

You create variable `name1` inside `if` statement inside `pictureBox1_Click()`. You should create class level variable to use it inside `button1_Click()`, because `name1` is visible only inside `if` block:

```
public YourClass
{    
    string name1 = String.Empty:

    //..... your code

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd1.Title = "Select User Profile Image";
        ofd1.Filter = "Image File(*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
        if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd1.FileName);
            name1 = ofd1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Compare(name1,name2);
    }

    public void Compare(string bmp1, string bmp2, byte threshold = 3)
    {
        Bitmap firstBmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(bmp1);
        Bitmap secondBmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(bmp2);
        firstBmp.GetDifferenceImage(secondBmp, true);
        string result = string.Format("Difference: {0:0.0} %", firstBmp.PercentageDifference(secondBmp, threshold) * 100);
    }
}
```

If you create `name2` the same way, you should make it class level variable too.

Comment: For absolute completeness its probably worth checking `name1` (and `name2`) for an empty string before trying to use them to load an image.

Comment: Jamiec how to load an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a member variable in your `Form` to save the file path:

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private string _imagePath1;
    private string _imagePath2;

   private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        // ... your code
        if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd1.FileName);
             // SAVE PATH TO CLASS MEMBER
             _imagePath1 = ofd1.FileName;
        }
   }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        // USE CLASS MEMBERS
        Compare(_imagePath1, _imagePath2);
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe someone thinks you copied his/her answer  :P :D

Comment: or, maybe someone doesnt like your destruction of naming conventions! (Even the OP got it right)

Comment: Though naming conventions would never be a reason for me to downvote an otherwise correct answer, I updated them. Camelcased by accident...

Comment: @RenéVogt - I agree. Whoever it was obviously felt guilty :)

Answer (score 0):

I think below URL is helpful to you

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/image-comparison-using-C-Sharp